# How to open all jstree nodes (parents and children)

Tags: javascript, jstree

There is a [webpage](http://www.worldfloraonline.org/classification#) that has 129 parent node.
And each parent node has multiple children to the fourth level (order>family>genus>specie).

I want to *Open-all* nodes.
I saw some posts here with a script to do that.
But I have no idea how to use it.

Note : my actual purpose is to copy all the data with its nested format.

*P.s. I'm not a web-dev and that's not my website.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will recursively expand all of the links then make a JSON out of it with the tree representation and then copy the JSON in your clipboard.

I set a timeout of 2 seconds for each tree to expand so that the children trees appear after the network request, so it will take 2 seconds * all of the available tree in that page, so you will have to wait a very long time for it to finish, if you have a fast connection you can reduce the timeout to 1 second to make it go faster.

```js
function extractChilds(ulNode) {
  return [...ulNode.childNodes].map(node => {
    let data = {
      title: node.querySelector('a')?.innerText?.trim()
    }
    let child = node.querySelector('ul');
    if(child) {
      data.childrens = extractChilds(child);
    }
    return data;
  });
}

async function main() {
  let done = false;

  while(!done) {
    for(const e of [...document.querySelectorAll('.jstree-closed')]) {
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000))
      e.querySelector('ins').click()
    }
    if(document.querySelectorAll('.jstree-closed').length === 0) done = true;
  }
  console.log('expanded all of the trees')
  return extractChilds(document.querySelector("#classification > ul"));
}

main().then(copy);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want! But, how do I use it? Do I just paste it in console tab and execute? Because it gives me   "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: yes, all you have to do is to paste it into the console, I tried with my chrome browser and did not face that error, at the end of the error, it will give you a line number. Let me know the browser and line number so that I can have a look.

Comment: I rechecked again. Somehow I messed the script when copying from phone to PC. Works like a charm now. Thanks a ton!